# Calculating distance in polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, distance, proximity

I want to show on map what's the distance between polygon A and B, but the result should be specified in polygons.

Here's the result similar to my idea:

[image]

I am working on ArcGIS Desktop.

Which tools should I use to get this result?